# How do I add "CST" time zone in the timestamp in the Google sheets code below? Also, will it know Daylight savings time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, timezone

Everything works on this code for me except for when the timestamp happens it's 2 hours behind my actual time. How do I get it to know CST time zone or is it something within Google Sheets that needs to be changed? This is my first time using code and I'm surprised I've gotten this far.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheets = ['TK Assignments']; // Which sheets to run the code.

  // Columns with the data to be tracked. 1 = A, 2 = B...
  var ind = [15, 17, 19].indexOf(e.range.columnStart); 

  // Which columns to have the timestamp, related to the data cells.
  // Data in 1 (A) will have the timestamp in 4 (D)
  var stampCols = [16, 18, 20]

  if(sheets.indexOf(sh.getName()) == -1 || ind == -1) return;

  // Insert/Update the timestamp.
  var timestampCell = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, stampCols[ind]);
  timestampCell.setValue(typeof e.value == 'object' ? null : new Date());
```

Comment: The Apps Script file and the spreadsheet file, both have their own timezone setting.  The default time zone settings in the script and Sheet files is the time zone in your browser.  When a date is created in the code, it's created with the script's time zone, not the Sheets timezone.  Do you have users in other time zones?  Did you change the time zone settings from the default in either the script or Sheet?  Is this just one Sheet with multiple users?  Are people making copies of the Sheet?

Comment: In the script editor go to `Files/Project Properties`.  On the `Info tab` scroll down near the bottom and see Timezone.  Set it to whatever you wish.  The Spreadsheet also has a timezone setting in `Files/Spreadsheet Settings`.  In `Utilities.formatDate( new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone() , "MM/dd/yy HH:mm")` getScriptTimeZone() will get the timezone setting found in `Files/Project Properties`.

Answer (score 1):

The Apps Script file and the spreadsheet file, both have their own timezone setting. The default time zone settings in the script and Sheet files is the time zone in your browser. When a date is created in the code, it's created by default with the script's time zone, not the Sheets timezone.

You can:

**1. Modify the script timezone**

- Within the script editor, go to `File>Project Properties`. In the `Info` tab, scroll down near the bottom and select the "Time zone" setting as you wish. Since those are "Time zones" (and not offsets) they will consider DST. If you want, you can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

**2. Use the Spreadsheet's settings Timezone**

- The Spreadsheet also has a timezone setting in `Files>Spreadsheet Settings`.
- Within the script. you can use `Utilities.formatDate( new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone() , "MM/dd/yy HH:mm")`. The `getScriptTimeZone()` function will get the timezone settings found in `Files/Project properties`.
- If, for some reason, you prefer to use a Timezone different than the one set in your Script settings or your Sheet settings, you can set whichever you prefer upon calling `Utilities.formatDate()`. You can see more information here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format

Comment: Thank you everyone, I went to settings in the sheet and was able to change my time zone. So easy!! Although my script stopped working, I can't get the time stamp to happen anymore which is frustrating. Still working on resolving that.